# Java applet works in appletviewer, Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet, appletviewer

OS: Mac OS X 10.7.3
Chrome: 19.0.1051.0 canary
Java: 32-bit and 64-bit version of Java SE 6

Directory structure:

- page.html
- Test.jar

  - META-INF

    - MANIFEST.MF
    - SELF-SIG.SF
    - SELF-SIG.DSA
  - com

    - tyilo

      - Test

        - Test$1.class
        - Test.class

page.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing applet</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
        <script type="application/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
            <param name="code" value="com.tyilo.Test.Test">
            <param name="archive" value="Test.jar">
            Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Test.java:

```
package com.tyilo.Test;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.security.AccessControlException;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Test extends JApplet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String text;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {   
        text = "~/test.txt created successfully!";
        try
        {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/test.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write("Testing123");
            out.close();
        }
        catch(AccessControlException e)
        {
            text = "File permission error.";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            text = "Unknown error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(text, 50, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void start()
    {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void stop()
    {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Java console error in chrome:

```
load: class com.tyilo.Test.Test not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tyilo.Test.Test
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tyilo.Test.Test
```

**Edit**
The code seems to run fine in the latest stable version of chrome, so this might just be a bug in the canary version.

**Edit 2**

There is only a problem with chrome when running the html (and jar) locally.

Comment: Good question.  Why are there empty `style` & `script` structures in the HTML?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Because I used my html template, which includes those. I might need them later...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise deployjava.js
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Enable java in chrome, to do this, type javascript:if(browser.value.getIndex("chrome"){chrome.browser.enableFeature(JApplet)}); in to chrome